# Low Yearly Archives inside dynamo form?

Tags: low-yearly-archives

It's all good on a refresh, but once the form is submitted, all goes wacky.

```
{exp:dynamo:form return="/events_keynote" search_id="{segment_2}"}

{exp:low_yearly_archives channel="public_events" end_year="2013" status="not closed" sort="desc"}
      {if year_count == 1}
      <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
        <select name="year" class="form-control">
          <option value="">Year</option>
            <option value="">All Years</option>
          {/if}
          <option value="{year}">{year}</option>
          {if year_count == total_years}
          </select>
</div>
      {/if}
      {/exp:low_yearly_archives}

{/exp:dynamo:form}
```

After a submit, all the yearly option values become blank. I have tried parse inward, dynamic=no, etc.... nothing will seem to make it work.

Is there something I am doing wrong or are these two plugins just simply incompatible? If so, it really unfortunate.

Please help!

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The two add-ons aren't compatible, but you might have more luck using [Mo’ Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables), which gives you the variable `{post:year}` to work with, amongst others.